# Selecting ContentView based on condition in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I have to display a button or a label depending on the value of some data.

I have a `ContentView` that displays data in a `Grid` and this is where I need to figure out a way to display the button or the label. I've used `selectors` before but it was always in a `CollectionView`.

Is there a way to use a `selector` in a `Grid`?

```xml
<ContentView
   xmlns:model="MyApp.Models"
   x:DataType="model:MyModel">
    
   <Grid
      RowDefinitions="75,75,75,*">
    
      <Label
         Grid.Row="0"
         Text="{Binding Property1}" />
    
      <Label
         Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding Property2}" />
    
      <!-- This is where I need to either render the button or a label -->
    
   </Grid>
    
</ContentView>
```

Separately, I have two `ContentView`'s i.e. `MyButtonView` and `StatusView` that I will use depending on the data. Just not sure how to handle the decision making process. I was thinking using a `selector` may work nicely here.

Comment: This was an annoying omission from XF. IIRC, I ended up making a CollectionView with an ItemsSource containing a single item, to control the selector. Unless someone has a new technique for Maui.

Comment: I guess I could always place both the `Button` and the `Label` there and control rendering using their `IsVisible` property but that feels really kludgy.

Comment: do it in the code behind.  XAML isn't the answer to every problem

Comment: What does the data look like? You can also use multi-bindings to control the visibility of ContentViews.

Comment: @Julian It’s actually a `bool` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just dealing with a `bool`, you can simply control the visibility of the Button and the Label using their `IsVisible` property in combination with your `bool` and the [InvertedBoolConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/inverted-bool-converter) from the MAUI Community Toolkit (MCT):

```xml
<ContentView
   xmlns:model="MyApp.Models"
   xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
   x:DataType="model:MyModel">

   <ContentView.Resources>
       <mct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter" />
   </ContentView.Resources>

   <Grid
      RowDefinitions="75,75,75,*">

      <Label
         Grid.Row="0"
         Text="{Binding Property1}" />

      <Label
         Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding Property2}" />

      <!-- This is where I need to either render the button or a label -->

      <!-- Show StatusView when value is true, hide it if false -->
      <StatusView
         Grid.Row="2"
         IsVisible="{Binding YourBool}" />

      <!-- Show MyButtonView when value is false, hide it if true -->
      <MyButtonView
         Grid.Row="2"
         IsVisible="{Binding YourBool, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}" />

   </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

If you don't want to use the MCT, you can also implement the `InvertedBoolConverter` yourself:

```cs
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp.Converters;

public class InvertedBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

I know that you find this solution "kludgy", but this is quite a common way of doing it in simple scenarios. It's less complex than using data templates and a template selector and I usually recommend taking the easiest path.